# Time series with slightly unequal intervals

Tags: time-series, prediction, definition

I'm very new to statistics, and I have a problem that may or may not exactly be considered a time series analysis problem. I have a large set of vehicle location measurements (x0, y0)...(xt, yt) taken over time measurements 0...t, and I would like to be able to predict the location at time t+1. The issue is, the differences between consecutive measurements aren't exactly equal; each is ~15 seconds, but can range from 14-16 seconds. Could this still be considered a time series analysis problem, or will certain methods fail when the delta of time isn't constant?